# VS2015 specrun integration

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow, specrun

I'm trying to debug tests in Visual Studio 2015, but I get the error:

> Configuration error: Invalid tool integration specified. Possible
>   values: None, VS2010, VS2012, VS2013, TeamCity, TFS

I have installed SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2015 (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c74211e7-cb6e-4dfa-855d-df0ad4a37dd6), but I'm probably missing something, just can't figure out what?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Cheers - Ole Andreas

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow+Runner (aka SpecRun) has support for VS2015 since version 1.3.